# Best way to import data using Axon Framwork

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, axon

What is the best way to import an excel file (or do mass insert) containing entities using the Axon Framework ?
Should we use a command with the excel file as a byte array, then parse the file in the Aggregate and send them each line as an event ? or create an event the list of entities (but then how to update aggregates) ? or parse the excel file outside of the aggregate and then create command of each row ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, you have two options *(each with many variations)*:

1. Parse the file on the client-side and issue a command per record
2. Send one command with the entire content *(the file itself or the content converted to another format)*. The command handler *(aggregate or not)* then iterates over the records and performs the required action per each.

Which one you choose and how exactly do you implement it depends on a lot of factors, such as:

- whether or not the data is about "entities" that are part of the same aggregate or not
- the size of the data (both in bytes and number of records)
- the performance and security requirements and constraints
- what information needs to be stored *(namely, should the system "remember" there was a "mass insert")*
- are the aggregates event-sourced or state-stored
- ...

As you can see, there are way too many possibilities for anyone to be able to give you a generic "best way".

That said, it is a very interesting question that can spark some architectural discussions. Unfortunately, StackOverflow is not the right place to have those (see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)).

If you would like to discuss those options in more detail I suggest posting the question on [AxonIQ's Discuss platform](https://discuss.axoniq.io/).

Comment: What if I'm certain my data is valid, static initial content (part of the source code)... then it seems that the "required action" in your #2 would be to load it directly into the event store. I don't want to fire the events as I import but I do want them there for event sourcing in the aggregates (ie to be replayed on every command)... so how do I import directly to the - say JPA - event store? How do I export?

Comment: One thing, I can think of is to have a flag in the event that indicates if it's an import or not. Then your event handlers can decide whether to take action or not based on that flag.

Answer (score 0):

it pretty much depends on what kind of Event is valuable for your business.

But in general, parsing the file outside of the Aggregate (this is not what the Aggregate is used for) and firing multiple commands (one for each line) would be my choice.
In that case, you will have an Event on your EventStore for each line which will make it way more explicity about what happened. Also, important to note that in this case, your Events will be granular and not that big, which usually I see as a code smell =)

KR,

Comment: Thanks. In that case I'll have to go thought a controller and eventually a service who will read the excel file and then create command. In my mind, with such framework, we try to avoid services. My Microservice can be invoked either by UI or by another microservices. I try to limit the usage of controller and privilege the usage of command and query... but in this case, i think that It's not possible (in the philosophy) and I have to use the controller and service to do the job of reading the file.

Comment: It pretty much depends where your file is located. What do you get on the Controller? Is it the id/url of the file you can fetch somewhere? In that case, you better have a service where you can do that. Another approach is to 'delegate' the reading of the file to an External Event Handler meaning you can fire an Event on your controller with the id/url notifying any component that a file need to be read/parsed/processed. Than your external EH would parse the file and fire multiple commands. Of course you have to be careful about replaying such event.